# How do I prevent re-export in generated 'index.ts' by graphql-codegen

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, next.js13, graphql-codegen

I use @graphql/codegen-cli to autogenerate my graphql typings using the below config...

```
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: 'schema.graphql',
  documents: 'src/**/*.graphql',
  generates: {
    'src/pages/api/graphql/generated/': {
      preset: 'client',
      plugins: [],
      config: {},
    },
    './graphql.schema.json': {
      plugins: ['introspection'],
    },
  }
};

export default config;
```

Amongst the generated files, the 'index.ts' file looks like so...

```
export * from './fragment-masking';
export * from './gql';
```

This causes a re-export error with next.js in production.
I need help to fix this automatically, perhaps during the generation process.